# AttributeError: module 'ntpath' has no attribute 'splittext'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, rutas, os

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime


content = os.listdir("when")
print(content)
#['2022_-_12_-_29 12pp33 am _--_ 2023_-_01_-_25 19pp13 pm.txt', '2023-02-05 00pp00 am.txt']

for i in range(len(content)):
    content[i] = content[i].replace("_-_", "-").replace("pp", ":")
#['2022-12-29 12:33 am _--_ 2023-01-25 19:13 pm.txt', '2023-02-05 00:00 am.txt']

#cleaned_filename = splittext(content[0])[0] #="2022-12-29 12:33 am _--_ 2023-01-25 19:13 pm"
cleaned_filename = os.path.splittext(content[0])[0]

start_dt = datetime.strptime(content[0].split(" _--_ ")[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="2022-12-29 12:33 am" = datetime(2022, 12, 29, 12, 33)
last_dt = datetime.strptime(content[0].split(" _--_ ")[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="2023-01-25 19:13 pm"

#third_dt = datetime.strptime(splittext(content[1])[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
third_dt = datetime.strptime(os.path.splittext(content[1])[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
#="2023-02-05 00:00 am"
```

A que se podría deber la aparición de este `AttributeError` en este código(uso Windows 10 y Python 3.6)? A que se refiere con `ntpath` , la verdad es que nunca importo esa librería si quiera en el código, y si la uso en lugar de `os`, da exactamente el mismo `AttributeError`.

En este link dan uso de este método con esta sintaxis `os.path.splittext(path, return type)`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-splitext-method/

Comment: Hola Matias, **cleaned_filename = os.path.splittext(content[0])[0]**, no será **cleaned_filename = splittext(content[0])[0]**

Comment: Si uso solo eso, me da el error `NameError: name 'splittext' is not defined`

Comment: Mati, creo que es **splitext**, aparte fijate que en algunos lugares lo llamas con **os.path.splittext** y en otros **splittext**.

Comment: Listo muchas gracias si era **os.path.splitext**

Comment: Un placer Mati.